# Travis build error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

Tags: ios, xcodebuild

#### when i build by travis, it alway failed on below:

---

▸ Building Travis/Travis [Release]

▸ Check Dependencies

❌  Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

#### The next error:

▸ Building Pods/pop [Release]

▸ Check Dependencies

▸ Building Pods/Pods-Travis [Release]

▸ Check Dependencies

▸ Building Travis/Travis [Release]

▸ Check Dependencies

❌  Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

#### but when i build by teminal, It's work fine. and i compare the console between the travis and terminal. i find the deffiences:

Building library libPods-Travis.a

▸ Building library libPods-Travis.a

▸ Building Travis/Travis [Release]

▸ Check Dependencies #######

▸ Running script '[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock'

▸ Compiling ViewController.m

#### Below:

Building Pods/Pods-Travis [Release]

▸ Check Dependencies

▸ Building Travis/Travis [Release]

▸ Check Dependencies ######

▸ Running script '[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock'

▸ Running script '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks'

▸ Running script '[CP] Copy Pods Resources'

▸ Build Succeeded

#### Please tell me where i am wrong?

#### How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I have fix this problem by check provision file if matching the Code Signing Identifier.

And i have a advice that should build in local terminal, and fix the problem if find.

Comment: wait, how did you fix this?

Comment: @CQM did you build in the local terminal ?

Comment: yes, local terminal builds fine, my build server (Circle-CI) doesn't

Comment: @CQM please check your cer and provisioning file is correct in Travis configure.

Comment: @CQM please check your cer and provisioning file is correct in Travis configure.